# JMeter - Using Variables in XML scripts with $ references where the values are selected by ODBC connection to a database

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter

In JMeter :
I have to set up a DataBase with an ODBC that I'm hoping to use to streamline XML content in Jmeter scripts. When my data changes, I would just change it in the database instead of in each script.  I've set up the JDBC connection and Request and specified variables that correspond with the columns in my table.  I have referenced these variables in my XML with `${example}` but I cannot get it to work.

I have done this with the CSV successfully but this method does not allow me to read the records by key field.